# Output a pdf from php using a query from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, fpdf

We're doing a project and we needed to have a report that is filtered and improved. Using a query from the database I have done it`select product,(select avg(numberPer)  from ( select product,count(*) as numberPer,
monthname(orderdate) as orderMonth, extract(day from orderdate) as orderDay from joborders 
group by product,orderMonth,orderDay having orderMonth = "March" and product = "Year Book")alias)as 
averagePerMonth ,monthname(orderdate) as orderMonth from joborders group by product,orderMonth 
having orderMonth = "March" and product = "Year Book"`.

Now we need to view the report as a pdf which where everything went haywire. After some editing of previous code from FPDF template, here is my code:

```
<?php
define('FPDF_FONTPATH', 'font/');
require('mysql_table.php');

class PDF extends PDF_MySQL_Table
{
function Header()
{
//Title
$this->SetFont('Arial', '', 18);
$this->Cell(0, 6, 'Job Orders', 0, 1, 'C');
$this->Ln(10);
//Ensure table header is output
parent::Header();
}
}

//Connect to database
include("connect.php");

$pdf=new PDF();
$pdf->Open();
$pdf->AddPage();
//First table: put all columns automatically
$pdf->Table('select product,(select avg(numberPer)  from ( select product,count(*) as          numberPer,
monthname(orderdate) as orderMonth, extract(day from orderdate) as orderDay from joborders 
group by product,orderMonth,orderDay having orderMonth = "March" and product = "Year   Book")alias)as 
averagePerMonth ,monthname(orderdate) as orderMonth from joborders group by  product,orderMonth 
having orderMonth = "March" and product = "Year Book"');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Now I would want to know why it errors:

> FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file.

Comment: Make sure you dont have an echo on mysql_table.php or connect.php

Comment: You cannot print/display/echo any output to your stream before you instantiate your PDF.

Comment: @RobertRozas mysql_table.php and connect.php has no echo.. mysql_table.php contains the class of PDF_MySQL_Table and connect.php contains the MySQL Connection.

Comment: Incidentally, while I appreciate that JOINs are deeply unfashionable, they might serve a purpose here!

Comment: @Strawberry I have an other queries where I use JOIN. This was just a test to see if it viewing the pdf report would work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this line:

```
ob_end_clean();
```

Between those:

```
$pdf->Table('select product,(select avg(numberPer)  from ( select product,count(*) as           numberPer,
monthname(orderdate) as orderMonth, extract(day from orderdate) as orderDay from joborders 
group by product,orderMonth,orderDay having orderMonth = "March" and product = "Year    Book")alias)as 
averagePerMonth ,monthname(orderdate) as orderMonth from joborders group by  product,orderMonth 
having orderMonth = "March" and product = "Year Book"');
ob_end_clean(); // HERE
$pdf->Output();
```